# Firefox PDF viewer events

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf

A big feature in Firefox (starting with v19 i think) is that Firefox ofers now a PDF documents viewer.

Is possible to interact with this add-on so that i know when a user click print for example?

Answer (score 1):

After i discussed with guys from pdf.js i conclude that this is not possible at this moment.

Pdf.js does not expose any embedded viewer functionality to interact with the container page. So you can not use addEventListener.

The only solution at this moment is to host your own pdf.js and modify the code to make the actions you need.